# PHP Array - Ordering

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$scores` as per below.

What I am trying to do is sort the array based on the numeric value in a descending order. I've tried defining functions like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) and other ways but haven't been able to do it. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

------------------------------------------------------------updated------------------------------------------------------------

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'B.Howell', 1 => 16.8, ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'B.Osweiler', 1 => 14.88, ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'K.Ballage', 1 => 13.7, ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'F.Owusu', 1 => 8.8, ), 4 => array ( 0 => 'I.Ford', 1 => 6.3, ), 5 => array ( 0 => 'B.Radcliff', 1 => 6.4, ), 6 => array ( 0 => 'D.Fales', 1 => 3.96, ), 7 => array ( 0 => 'L.Carroo', 1 => 4.9, ), 8 => array ( 0 => 'R.Scott', 1 => 2.5, ), 9 => array ( 0 => 'M.Lewis', 1 => 2.4, ), 10 => array ( 0 => 'T.Duarte', 1 => 3.2, ), 11 => array ( 0 => 'J.Langford', 1 => 2.8, ), 12 => array ( 0 => 'A.Derby', 1 => 1.1, ), 13 => array ( 0 => 'D.Morgan', 1 => 1.2, ), )
```

The solutions offered using `usort` I've tried previously and could not get them to work and still can't. It does tend to sort the array in somewhat of a descending order, however, there still exists outliers, see the following before and after images.

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    return $b[1] - $a[1];
}

usort($scores, 'mySort');
```

[image: BEFORE IMAGE]

[image: AFTER IMAGE]

Comment: please share the code that you are using

Comment: Show code what you wrote.

Comment: Hi, as with most questions on SO it is always a good idea to show us the code you have tried. It adds some context to your problem which helps us to help you.

Comment: As none of it has been working I haven't kept any of it. However, yes, I'll re-create it and post.

Comment: Its also a good idea to show your array using `var_export($array);` as we can copy paste that directly into a test script to prove our answer work

Comment: `var_export` has now been added and I've added some extra clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for **DESCENDING** order of numeric values

`$b['1'] - $a['1']` its sorts numeric value **descending** order

`$a['1'] - $b['1']` its sorts numeric value **ascending** order

```
<?php
$array = array ( array ('B.Osweiler',14.88 ), 
                 array ('D.Fales', 3.96), 
                 array ('B.Radcliff', 6.4 ), 
                 array ('K.Ballage', 13.7 ), 
                 array ('J.Langford', 2.8 ),
                 array ('B.Howell', 16.8 ) );

print "Before Sort". PHP_EOL;;
print_r($array);
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['1'] - $a['1']; //see this line carefully
});

print "After Sort". PHP_EOL;
print_r($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bWdIq

**EDIT:** I've added the edit as per the new modification on the question that will fix your existing outliers.

```
<?php
$array = array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'B.Howell', 1 => 16.8, ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'B.Osweiler', 1 => 14.88, ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'K.Ballage', 1 => 13.7, ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'F.Owusu', 1 => 8.8, ), 4 => array ( 0 => 'I.Ford', 1 => 6.3, ), 5 => array ( 0 => 'B.Radcliff', 1 => 6.4, ), 6 => array ( 0 => 'D.Fales', 1 => 3.96, ), 7 => array ( 0 => 'L.Carroo', 1 => 4.9, ), 8 => array ( 0 => 'R.Scott', 1 => 2.5, ), 9 => array ( 0 => 'M.Lewis', 1 => 2.4, ), 10 => array ( 0 => 'T.Duarte', 1 => 3.2, ), 11 => array ( 0 => 'J.Langford', 1 => 2.8, ), 12 => array ( 0 => 'A.Derby', 1 => 1.1, ), 13 => array ( 0 => 'D.Morgan', 1 => 1.2, ), );


print '<pre>';
print "Before Sort". PHP_EOL;;
print_r($array);
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if($a[1]==$b[1]){
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a[1] > $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
});

print "After Sort". PHP_EOL;
print_r($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/c4UmQ

Comment: Guess the OP has taken one of our answers and disappreared into the ether :) SO +1 from me

Comment: ha ha :) I also think so :)

Comment: Hey guys, sorry, Australian time meant I went to sleep and then worked all day so I didn't go running with solution. In fact this solution I'd tried before based on the link i had in the question and it unfortunately didn't work for me. I've added extra clarification in the question explaining this now. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Morts81 I've added a new demo as per  your question modification. See my edit and let me know whether it is working for you or not now?

Comment: Thanks @smart-googler this works perfectly. Very much appreciated, I imagine this has something to do with the extra comma in each part of the array but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `usort()` like this

```
$arr = [ ['B.Osweiler', 14.88],
         ['D.Fales', 3.96 ],
         ['B.Radcliff', 6.4 ],
         ['K.Ballage', 13.7 ], 
         ['J.Langford', 2.8 ],
         ['B.Howell', 16.8 ] 
        ];

function mySort($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
}

usort($arr, 'mySort');
print_r($arr);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => J.Langford
            [1] => 2.8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => D.Fales
            [1] => 3.96
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B.Radcliff
            [1] => 6.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => K.Ballage
            [1] => 13.7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => B.Osweiler
            [1] => 14.88
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => B.Howell
            [1] => 16.8
        )

)
```